# Ruby model with an array as an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, modeling

I am currently trying to implement a model to simplify graphical chart creation. However, one of the attributes must be an array of attributes. For example:

"Chart_Series" has a "name" which would be a string and a data field which would be separated by dates which is an array of arrays [[Date1, Value1],[Date2,Value2],[Date3,Value3].

The purpose is to create an array of "Chart_Series" so as to call upon something like:

```
for series in @chart_series
  series.name 
     for data in series.data
      data.[Date, Value]
     end    
end
```

which would do something along the lines of:

```
  Name1
      Date1, Value1
      Date2, Value 2,
      Date3, Value 3,
      Date4, Value 4,
  Name2 
      Date1, Value 1,
      Date2, Value 2,
      Date3, Value 3,
      Date4, Value 4,
```

This is not exactly the code desired.. I am interested in simply generating the model which could do something like this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two initial approaches, namely define a class to represent your key,value pair or just use a hash to represent each data item. The advantage of a separate class is that you can extend it in the future, if for example you wanted to provide the exact value in a chart where  you were rounding to the nearest 100k.

The following code shows three classes which together will do what you want

```
class Chart

  attr_accessor :title, :series

  def initialize(title = nil, series = [])
    @title, @series = title, series
  end

  def show
    puts title
    @series.each do |ser|
      puts "\t#{ser.legend} (#{ser.units})"
      ser.data.each do |item|
        puts "\t\t#{item}"
      end
    end
  end

end

class Series

  attr_accessor :legend, :units, :data

  def initialize(legend = nil, units = nil, data = [])
    @legend, @units, @data = legend, units, data
  end

end

class DataItem
  attr_accessor :key, :value

  def initialize(key, value)
    @key, @value = key, value
  end

  def to_s
    "#{key}, #{value}"
  end

end
```

Running this as follows :-

```
c = Chart.new("Sweet sales by Quarter")
c.series << Series.new("Bon-Bons", "£000", 
  [ DataItem.new("Q1", 220), 
    DataItem.new("Q2", 280), 
    DataItem.new("Q3", 123), 
    DataItem.new("Q4", 200)]
)
c.series << Series.new("Humbugs", "£000",  
  [ DataItem.new("Q1", 213), 
    DataItem.new("Q2", 254), 
    DataItem.new("Q3", 189), 
    DataItem.new("Q4", 221)]
)

c.show
```

Produces the following output

```
Sweet sales by Quarter
    Bon-Bons (£000)
        Q1, 220
        Q2, 280
        Q3, 123
        Q4, 200
    Humbugs (£000)
        Q1, 213
        Q2, 254
        Q3, 189
        Q4, 221
```

If you wanted to take the Hash approach then you would no longer need the DataItem class and you could instantiate a new Series with code like this

```
c = Chart.new("Sweet sales by Quarter")
c.series << Series.new("Bon-Bons", "£000", 
   [ { "Q1" => 220}, {"Q2" => 280}, {"Q3" => 123}, {"Q4" => 200}]
)
```

The show method of Chart would then look like this

```
  def show
    puts title
    @series.each do |ser|
      puts "\t#{ser.legend} (#{ser.units})"
      ser.data.each do |item|
        item.each_pair {|key, value| puts "\t\t#{key}, #{value}" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you Steve, i believe you nailed it. Im using highcharts javavascript library. So with these classes, creating these charts will be much simpler

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend to use a relational database backend with ActiveRecord then I beleive you need (at least) two models. Something like this:

```
class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :data_points
end

class DataPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chart
end
```

Your `Chart` model would have the `name` attribute and the `DataPoint` model would have the `date` and `value` attributes.

Then you can reference your data points, as an association, like this:

`@chart.data_points`

so it looks like an array attribute, even though it is an association with another model

Comment: This is a good idea, however I am not using a Database for this specific Model, since this Model will be populated by a query of a huge database and my only interest is to chart it..I am currently trying something out with hashes...Il repost if i have a breaktrough..Thanks!

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. If you don't need the series to be a persistent attribute of the `Chart` then just create an array or hash as a class attribute and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You try something like this

Say you have a class called User and you need to generate its attributes dynamically, you can do this like this,

class User
 User.class_exec{
   %w[name age address].each{|i|
      attr_accessor i
   }
 }
end

this will create a User class with attributes 
name, age and address

and you can use this as

a = User.new
a.name = "sameera"
a.age = "29"
a.address = "home town"
puts a.inspect

hope this helps

cheers
sameera